# Magento2 Need to get Customer details & customer custom attribute value while creating new order via admin

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

Magento2 How can I get the customer details & customer custom attribute while creating new order from admin

As using the customer custom attribute value I need to restrict payment method from loading

My custom attribute is yes/no type. If value is yes for particular customer then show payment method else if no then hide payment method.